# Writing arabic letters in java desn't work with runnable jar file

Tags: java, arabic, executable-jar, fileoutputstream

I am using this code to write a String to a text file. The String is a combination of English and  Arabic letters. When I run the code in eclipse it works fine but when I extract the code to a Runnable JAR file and run it all Arabic letters are replaced by a question mark.

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), "UTF-8"); 
bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);

bw.write("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>");
```

Comment: What OS? How are you looking at the output file?

Comment: In which editor are you viewing the file? Maybe it doesn't support UTF-8?